# What's The Error In this code

Tags: c#, asp.net

this code works fine in php to generate the custom scripts generators

```
 <?php

    $arrs = array("script.js","ui.js","jform.js");


    foreach ($arrs as $var)
    {
    ?>


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $var ?>" >
</script>

<?php

    }


    ?>
```

this not compiling even whts the probem in my code the aspx but its not working

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%              IList<string> list;

list = new List<string>();

foreach (string lst in list)
{ 
%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%  lst  %>"   />

<%  



 }
     %>
```

Comment: Well if it's not *compiling*, presumably there's a compiler error message, which should tell you the problem. Even if you don't understand the message, you should at least share it with us...

Comment: Try use: <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= lst %>" />

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want ..

Answer (score 1):

You error is with script line change the line to below resolve your one issue..i tried in my environment

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% =lst %>"   />
```

Full code will be :

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%  IList<string> list;

    list = new List<string>();

    foreach (string lst in list)
    { 
   %>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<% = lst %>"  />

   <%      
   }
   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%  IList<string> list;

    list = new List<string>();

    foreach (string lst in list)
    { 
   %>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<% = lst %>"  />

   <%      
   }
   %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ..
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

 <%  var list = new List<string>() { "script.js", "ui.js", "jform.js" };
        foreach (string lst in list)
        { 
    %>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=  lst %>"></script>

    <%      
        }
    %>
```